# Images repeat in recycler view

Tags: android, image, random, android-recyclerview

I have set of images to display in Recycler View in random way. The issue is that images repeat and not all images are used. What  I need is: all images used and display each of them only once (no repeat). Thank you in advance for help.

```
public class Article {
private int mTitle;

private static int[] sTitles = {
        R.drawable.image1a,
        R.drawable.image2a,
        ....
        R.drawable.image30a
};
public Article() {

   Random random = new Random();
```

// Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(sTitles));// Tried to use this but no success

```
 mTitle = sTitles[random.nextInt(sTitles.length)];
}
public int getTitle() {
    return mTitle;

}
```

Edit: My adapter code

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ArrayList<Article> mArticles = new ArrayList<>();
```

public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

```
private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView mTitle;


    public MyViewHolder(View pItem) {
        super(pItem);

        mTitle = (ImageView) pItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Article> pArticles, RecyclerView pRecyclerView) {
    mArticles = pArticles;
    mRecyclerView = pRecyclerView;


}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.article_layout, viewGroup, false);

         return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    Article article = mArticles.get(i);

    ((MyViewHolder) viewHolder).mTitle.setImageResource(article.getTitle());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mArticles.size();

}
```

Comment: Can you provide your the code for the adapter?

Comment: added adapter code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Article class to this:

```
public class Article {
    private int mTitle;

    private static int[] sTitles = {
            R.drawable.image1a,
            R.drawable.image2a,
            ....
            R.drawable.image30a
    };

    public Article(int title) {
        this.mTitle = title;
    }

    public int getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getRandomArticles() {
        ArrayList<Integer> titles = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> tempTitles = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(sTitles));
        Collections.shuffle(tempTitles);
        for(int title : tempTitles) {
            titles.add(title);
        }
        return titles;
    }
}
```

Then when you create your Adapter pass Article.getRandomArticles() as the Article List like this:

```
new MyAdapter(Article.getRandomArticles(), yourRecyclerView);
```

EDIT: Forgot the return type of getRandomArticles

Comment: Thanks will try it

Comment: I have error with this (Array.asList(sTitles)); telling: Cannot resolve symbol "Array". It also greyed out getRandomArticles as never used.

Comment: Thats because I had a typo in my answer, sorry. It should be Arrays.asList not Array.asList. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are already shuffling the array and again you are picking random image from that shuffled array. That random picking causes you getting the same image again. So just pick the images off the array in their shuffled order. no need to pick random image.

**Edit:**

Change your array to list and Try something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> sTitles = new ArrayList<Integer>();
sTitles.add(R.drawable.image1a);
.
.
.
.
sTitles.add(R.drawable.image30a);
Collections.shuffle(sTitles );
```

Comment: When I have code without Collections.shuffle it happens as I described. But when I delete random the Collection.shuffle itself doesn't work at all and any picture is displayed.